'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'EmploymentDetails'
I am getting the above error could somebody help me understand why I am getting this error? I am using lombok annotations with hibernate.
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@Entity
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
public class PortfolioDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int yearsOfExperience;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PORTFOLIO_EMPLOYMENT_DETAILS",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PORTFOLIO_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYMENT_ID"))
    private Set<EmploymentDetails> employmentDetails;

    public PortfolioDetails(String name,int yearsOfExperience){
        this.name= name;
        this.yearsOfExperience =yearsOfExperience;
    }

}


Below is the employmentDetails class for your reference. I have multiple classes like these. Thanks in advance for your help.
@lombok.Getter
    @lombok.Setter
    public class EmploymentDetails {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String jobTitle;
        private String employmentType;
        private String client;
        private String employer;
        //private LocalDate startDate;
        //private LocalDate endDate;
        private String location;
        private String jobDescription;
        private String jobDuties;
        private String technologyStack;
    
        public EmploymentDetails(
         String jobTitle,
         String employmentType,
         String client,
         String employer,
         String location,
         String jobDescription,
         String jobDuties,
         String technologyStack){
            this.jobTitle =jobTitle;
            this.employmentType = employmentType;
            this.client = client;
            this.employer = employer;
            this.location = location;
            this.jobDescription = jobDescription;
            this.jobDuties = jobDuties;
            this.technologyStack = technologyStack;
        }
    }


EmploymentDetails class is missing the @Entity annotation.
